# Read Weight from a Serial Mettler Toledo Digital Scale

Tags: c#, .net, usb, serial-port

I am trying to read weight from digital scale in c# app, found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6569882/reading-data-from-mettler-toledo-scale-device-using-c-sharp) question
this is exactly what I am trying to do
but for me below function never runs.

```
private void port_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e) 
{ 
this.Invoke(new EventHandler(DoUpdate)); 
}
```

I have checked the scale in device manager, its location is set to `Port_#0004.Hub_#0003` and appear to be working fine
I was not sure about port number of the scale so I did

```
var test = SerialPort.GetPortNames();
```

and only `COM1` gets returned

`Edit 1:` When I do `int a = port.ReadByte();` my application hangs and execution never moves forward from this statement.

Comment: maybe the scale isn't giving you any data back? Use portmon to see if any data is being received by the computer.

Comment: If you don't have one already, you might need a driver to turn the USB connection into a virtual COMM port, otherwise opening the serial port will not connect to the USB device. EDIT SamFisher83's point is good, you might need to initialize it somehow to get it to send info.

Comment: @SamFisher83 I am on win 7 (x64) portmon now working, any alternatives?

Comment: The scale will always return a response if it receives a command. The response might be it saying that the command was not understood or the user passed bad parameters but so long as something is received something will be returned.

Comment: If this is a USB connection rather than a real serial port connection (with a d-sub connector directly to a physical port on your computer) then COM1 is probably wrong. Check the Device Manager on the Windows control panel to see if Windows is seeing the virtual com port. If you are unsure, unplug it and plug it back in again and see which port disappears then reappears. If you don't see anything, you are probably missing a driver.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10130837/connecting-to-digital-scalemetler-toledo-ps90-as-hid-runs-onreport-only-when-c) post, I used Mike library to connect.

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using HidLibrary;

namespace MagtekCardReader
{
    class Program
    {
        private const int VendorId = 0x0801;
        private const int ProductId = 0x0002;

        private static HidDevice _device;

        static void Main()
        {
            _device = HidDevices.Enumerate(VendorId, ProductId).FirstOrDefault();

            if (_device != null)
            {
                _device.OpenDevice();

                _device.Inserted += DeviceAttachedHandler;
                _device.Removed += DeviceRemovedHandler;

                _device.MonitorDeviceEvents = true;

                _device.ReadReport(OnReport);

                Console.WriteLine("Reader found, press any key to exit.");
                Console.ReadKey();

                _device.CloseDevice();
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Could not find reader.");
                Console.ReadKey();
            }
        }

        private static void OnReport(HidReport report)
        {
            if (!_device.IsConnected) { return; }

            var cardData = new Data(report.Data);

            Console.WriteLine(!cardData.Error ? Encoding.ASCII.GetString(cardData.CardData) : cardData.ErrorMessage);

            _device.ReadReport(OnReport);
        }

        private static void DeviceAttachedHandler()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Device attached.");
            _device.ReadReport(OnReport);
        }

        private static void DeviceRemovedHandler()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Device removed.");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I faced a problem like this and I solved it changing a `COM` configuration (`Configuration > Comunication > Conections`) to `SICS` in the device. I don't know your scale model but maybe my code can help. [[Reading data from Mettler Toledo (IND560) scale device using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35483240/reading-data-from-mettler-toledo-ind560-scale-device-using-c-sharp)]

Answer (score 0):

Could you try polling instead of using the DataReceived event? Also, I believe the DataReceived event has a threshold before it fires, you might want to look into that too.

Comment: on which property of port should i poll?

Comment: Set up a timer to periodically check BytesToRead on the serial port. Then use Read to read the data. Check the MSDN pages for more details: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/30swa673.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to get the serial number from the balance? This should be the first thing you do when connecting. It will let you verify the connection is established. If you are having trouble connecting through a C# interface try using HyperTerminal first. You can vary a lot of setting really quickly and dial in on the right ones to use. Although the balance should be able to use a wide variety of baud rates and stop bits and such. They are usually pretty adaptable. But do try HyperTerminal.

I'm looking for the pdf but there is a very long list of available commands (depending on your model). The pdf is like 130 pages long. Have you read this?

Comment: Thanks for answer 
1)Yes I have read the pdf, steps it says to do to verify USB connection is established were fine
2)Hyper Terminal is not avialble in win 7
3)When you say am I able to get serial number from balance, is it like a property of the scale that i can access through hardware setup?

Comment: The serial number is the response the balance returns when you specifically ask for it or when you issue a reboot command (both responses should look identical). It's the first thing to test for. Out of