# Reading data from Mettler Toledo (IND560) scale device using C#

Tags: c#, scale

I'm facing some problems when receiving data from Mettler Toledo (IND560) scale device using C#.

When I send "taring" command (T) to device, it's working properly but there is nothing in response. The BytesToRead is always empty and the "while" is in infinite loop.

When I send "send stable weight value" command (S), I face the same infinite loop issue. I guess the command is running properly but not responding.

Here is the code:

```
private decimal? BalancaIND560(string porta, string comando) {
    SerialPort SerialObj = new SerialPort(porta);
    if (!SerialObj.IsOpen)
        SerialObj.Open();

    string retorno = "";
    try {
        SerialObj.BaudRate = 9600;
        SerialObj.Parity = Parity.Even;
        SerialObj.DataBits = 7;
        SerialObj.StopBits = StopBits.One;
        SerialObj.Handshake = Handshake.XOnXOff;

        SerialObj.DiscardInBuffer();
        SerialObj.DiscardOutBuffer();

        SerialObj.Write(comando);

        while ((SerialObj.BytesToRead == 0))
            Application.DoEvents();

        Thread.Sleep(500);
        retorno = SerialObj.ReadExisting();

        SerialObj.DiscardInBuffer();
        SerialObj.DiscardOutBuffer();
    } finally {
        try { SerialObj.Close(); } catch { }
    }

    decimal? resultado = null;
    try {
        string[] aux = retorno.Split(' '); //"S S     100.52 kg"

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < aux.Length; i++)
            sb.Append(String.Format("aux[{0}]: {1}" + Environment.NewLine, i, aux[i]));
        MessageBox.Show(sb.ToString());

        decimal peso = 0.0M;
        if (!Decimal.TryParse(aux[6].Trim(), NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out peso))
            Decimal.TryParse(aux[7].Trim(), NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out peso);
        resultado = peso;
    } catch { }

    return resultado;
}

// Sending command
try {
    decimal? peso = BalancaIND560("COM1", "S");
    if (peso.HasValue)
        MessageBox.Show(String.Format("Peso: {0}", peso.Value));
    else
        MessageBox.Show("Peso não foi encontrado", "ATENÇÃO", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
} catch {
    MessageBox.Show("Erro ao executar comando", "ERRO", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
}
```

Comment: I found the solution! I just had to change a scale configuration and it's WORKING!!! If someone face the same problem, just change `COM` configuration (`Configuration > Comunication > Conections`) to `SICS` in the device and my code is working wonderfully!! Tks All!

Comment: Can you post all of your code from your project please? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution! I just had to change a scale configuration and it's WORKING!!! If someone face the same problem, just change `COM` configuration (`Configuration > Comunication > Conections`) to `SICS` in the device and my code is working wonderfully!! Tks All!