# How to read data from Mettler Toledo IND560 via Ethernet using C# socket

Tags: c#, tcp, ethernet

I'm trying to connect to Mettler Toledo IND560 scale device using c# application. Everything work fine in RS-232 connection, but it's not with Ethernet.

Following intruction in Mettler Toledo technical guide, i used HyperTerminal (port 1701) but no luck with that. It alway show connection error.

The same with C# application (Exception: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 192.168.1.xx:1701).

```
        private const int PORT_NUMBER = 1701;
        private const string cmd = "user admin";
        try
        {
            TcpClient client = new TcpClient();
            client.Connect("192.168.1.11",PORT_NUMBER);  //Error here
            Stream stream = client.GetStream();
            StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(stream);
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream);
            if (client.Connected)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Connected to Mettler Toledo IDN560");
                Console.WriteLine("Sending command: {0}\\n", cmd);

                writer.Write($" {cmd}" + '\n');
                writer.Flush();
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
                string str = reader.ReadLine();
                Console.WriteLine(str);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error");
            }
            Console.ReadKey();

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex); 
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
```

Expected respone from device is <12 ACCESS OK> but it is not.

What is wrong here ?!

Comment: Since you can't connect with a terminal program, it's probably not something in your program. How have you determined the IP address of the device? Can you ping it?

Comment: I set IP of the device is 192.168.1.11 with on board  terminal, and i can ping it.

Comment: It's worked for me with different IP and Port  , accept those 2 private const variables. They did setup in different port.

Answer (score 0):

In IND560 Terminal User’s Guide it says "The InSite™ configuration tool program is used to flash new terminal softwarethrough the COM1 serial port or Ethernet port." Have you tried to connect with this program?

Comment: Yes i have, unable to communicate with the device (Serial Port and Ethernet Port) :(.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9671294/read-weight-from-a-serial-mettler-toledo-digital-scale Have you used HidLibrary?

Comment: No i'm not, i'm just used System.Net.Socket . Is HidLibrary work?!

Answer (score 0):

in my case i'm using a IND780. The command sequence is:

1. user USERNAME
2. pass PASSWORD

After both commands you can now read the weight, for example:
READ wt0101 wt0102

I've used this library:
https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19071/Quick-tool-A-minimalistic-Telnet-library